# Event Listeners Chrome Dev Tools - extend jQuery - why do even listeners point to library instead of customized/extended script?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, extend, event-listener

Beginner / Intermediate developer here and trying to get a grasp on tracking down event listeners, but finding myself confused and frustrated because it always point to the library that handles the event, not the user's script.  Example from the Event Listeners accordion on a select element that has the "keyup" event bound:

```
keyup
    div.select
    handler: function (e){return typeof b===i||e&&b.event.triggered===e.typet:b.event.dispatch.apply(f.elem,arguments)}
    isAttribute: false
    lineNumber: 3
    listenerBody: "function (e){return typeof b===i||e&&b.event.triggered===e.type?t:b.event.dispatch.apply(f.elem,arguments)}"
    node: div.select
    sourceName: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"
    type: "keyup"
    useCapture: false
```

Obviously they are using jQuery, and they're doing a damn good job of it by using jQuery's $.extend method, but I still don't understand why the events accordion (in dev tools) would point to the library rather than the customized script?

Is there something really basic I missed in class?   What methods are there for tracking these types of things down aside from CTRL+F in the Resources tab, which, btw did not yield any search results for "select" in the file that ACTUALLY extends/adds this listener - very odd is it not?

**Update:** So I feel pretty dumb about this, but the answer was right in front of my eyes - or so I think.  At the top of their custom script they begin with,

```
define(["jquery"], function($) {
```

Could this be the beginning of the answer?  Really what I'd like to *understand* is why the event would still trace back to the library when the event listener is bound within the above code,

```
$el.textHolder.click(function(e){ 
    ... do stuff ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, this is because when jQuery binds an event, it doesn't bind it directly to your code, but instead to jQuery code that then dispatches the event to your code.
The Chrome devtools don't know (at this point, [it seems to be in development](https://plus.google.com/+AddyOsmani/posts/9WvgE2K2QTF)) how jQuery binds the event, so only shows the first handler (jQuery).

The define call is part of the [CommonJS Modules Standard](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1.1) I believe.  See also [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)